# WCF client request returns bad request (400)

Tags: c#, wcf

My client application use a WCF web service which is hosted in my local IIS. This web service use for upload an image. Once image size become bigger it gives bad request(400).

Client is configure to dynamically get the web service URL.

**Client Code**

```
string serviceUrl=GetUrl();  /* http://localhost:85/ImageUploaderService.svc */

TimeSpan timeOut = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);

EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl);     


BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
{
    CloseTimeout = timeOut,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536,
    OpenTimeout = timeOut,
    ReceiveTimeout = timeOut,
    SendTimeout = timeOut,
    MaxBufferSize = 65536,
    MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288,
    UseDefaultWebProxy = true,
};

binding.ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
{
    MaxArrayLength = 64000000,
    MaxStringContentLength = 8192,
    MaxDepth = 32,
    MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384,
    MaxBytesPerRead = 4096
};

client = new ImageUploaderServiceClient(binding, endPoint);
```

**Web Service side**

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferSize="64000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="64000000" maxBufferPoolSize="64000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64000000" maxStringContentLength="64000000" maxArrayLength="64000000" maxBytesPerRead="64000000" />
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

What is the wrong I am doing. Please guide me through the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase MaxReceivedMessageSize on client side as well probably:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
{
     MaxReceivedMessageSize = 64000000,
     MaxBufferSize = 64000000,
     MaxBufferPoolSize = 64000000,
// .....
};
binding.ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
{
    MaxArrayLength = 64000000,
    MaxStringContentLength = 64000000,
    MaxDepth = 64000000,
    MaxBytesPerRead = 64000000
};
```

I had the same problem once - the server and client binding configuration should be the same.

Comment: have you changed the settings of ReaderQuotas as well? They should also be the same as on server probably...

Comment: Yes. Now both sides are having same values.

Comment: Probably you reached the maximum packet size of HTTP request... What size of image to you need to transfer? If possible, I would recommend using NetTcpBinding instead of the BasicHttpBinding - it hasn't such limitation and it's much faster. Is it possible to change the binding type?

Comment: Change the binding to NetTcpBinding  or CustomBinding and add a service behavior and set maxitemsinobjectgraph value as 2,147,483,647